daterangepicker date change pass controller
My problem is such that when the view is opened, the date January 1, 0001 is visible in it. When I set breaker in the controller, the first time value remains January 1, 0001. After that, on continuing, the correct date is found in the controller. But the view is not updated please help me
How to do this, like may I change the date, get the date in the view accordingly and filter the data and show it in the controller.
my jQuery
>
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(function () {

                var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
                var end = moment();

                function cb(start, end) {
                    $('#DashboardDate span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
                    console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET", // or "POST" depending on your controller action
                        url: '@Url.Action("index", "Dashboard")', // adjust the URL to match your controller route
                        data: {
                            FromDate: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                            ToDate: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            // Handle the response from the controller if needed
                            console.log('Dates sent to controller successfully.' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.error('Error sending dates to controller:', error);
                        }
                    });
                }

                $('#DashboardDate').daterangepicker({
                    startDate: start,
                    endDate: end,
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    }
                }, cb);

                cb(start, end);

            });
        });
    </script>

my controller
 public IActionResult Index(DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
 {

     ViewBag.FromDate = FromDate;
     ViewBag.ToDate = ToDate;

     return View();
 }

my view
 <h3 class="mt-3 mb-3">@ViewBag.FromDate.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy")</h3>


you pasted the controller twice instead of the view

Could you try to set the nullable DateTime and set default values for FromDate and ToDate if they are not provided. try to modify the AJAX success function to update the DOM with the new dates using JavaScript, ensuring the view reflects the selected date range. make sure the date formats in JavaScript match those expected by the server. have you checked console logs?

I think that should be: FromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") in your view.  You might also check the results of your parsing in JS... sometimes you need to split on "T".  Check results of start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') with an alert or something.
